# Swap key €->$ permanently

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have a Macbook Air with a Swedish keyboard and when I type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> I get this: **€**. What I would like to get is **$** ,now at <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

How can I swap these two around?

Comment: For more information about how to use Ukelele, see this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/decimal-comma-in-spanish-keyboard-layout/2768#2768

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=Ukelele) that allows you to edit key mappings for free.