# Apple keyboard remap keypad comma to dot?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, mapping

Is there any way to change the key mapping of the apple keyboard?

As programmer I find annoying there's a comma instead a dot in numeric keypad. I would remap this key to have dot ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal comma in Spanish keyboard layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/decimal-comma-in-spanish-keyboard-layout)

Comment: Can you clarify which keyboard layout you are using?

Comment: Italian kb layout

Comment: It's still relevant question in 2022. Replace dot to comma: `{ "#." = ("insertText:", ","); }` or comma to dot: `{ "#," = ("insertText:", "."); }`.

Answer (score 39):

The simplest solution is to create the file  `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` in `/Users/[user]/Library/KeyBindings` if it does not already exist, and add the remapping:

```
{
   "#," = ("insertText:", ".");
}
```

Then logout or restart the mac.

The `#` indicates the remapping is for the keypad only. More reference for that file: https://gist.github.com/trusktr/1e5e516df4e8032cbc3d

Comment: Thanks ! I've been looking for something like this for few months. I didn't wanted to download a tool for this purpose....

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, +1 for not needing another tool. By the way, a restart isn't necessary, just log out and log back in.

Comment: This solution is working in Catalina (10.15 Beta) with no problems.

Comment: Working on Catalina 10.15.2

Comment: Hi! I wanted to achieve the same result but in reverse, so dot to a comma. I placed this: `{ "#." = ("insertText:". ","); } ` in `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried with `{ "#," = ("insertText:". ","); } `, but still not working... :(

Comment: This does not work everywhere. It does not work in JetBrains products.

Comment: Don't be disturbed if you need to actually **CREATE** both the `KeyBindings` folder and the `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` file. It worked perfectly on my Apple Silicon M1 Macbook. I used UTF-8 and LF line endings for the file format.

Answer (score 9):

based on Matías González answer:

Step 1, Add the remapping (paste this command on your console):

```
mkdir ~/Library/KeyBindings && cd ~/Library/KeyBindings && touch DefaultKeyBinding.dict && echo '{"#," = ("insertText:", ".");}' > DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

Step 2, Restart the mac

The `#` indicates the remapping is for the keypad only. More reference for that file: https://gist.github.com/trusktr/1e5e516df4e8032cbc3d

Comment: Would you get a comma again if you pressed shift this way? Because that would be desirable

Comment: I don’t think so, but feel free to give it a try and comment your findings

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is reading this in 2022 and using Mac OS X 12.1 (Monterey) and wants to change dot (<kbd>.</kbd>) to comma (<kbd>,</kbd>) on a number keypad, try the following steps:

1. Open the Terminal application;
2. Paste this code on it:

```
hidutil property --set '
{"UserKeyMapping": [
    {
        "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 0x700000063,
        "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 0x700000036
    },
]}'
```

3. Press enter;
4. Enjoy it!

`0x700000063` means dot char <kbd>.</kbd>

`0x700000036` means comma char <kbd>,</kbd>

---

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the update. Since I use a different keyboard layout (bépo), thanks to the table you have referenced, I managed to figure out that I needed to replace `0x700000063` by `0x700000019`. Now it works as expected    It prints a `v` when I change the keyboard back to French, but that's no big deal for me.

Comment: BTW if anyone wants to cancel their changes after experimenting with this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/374073/

Answer (score 2):

I changed my keyboard from "Dutch" to "US international - PC" and my numpad dot works as expected. It's no longer giving me a comma.

Comment: So easy and exactly what fixes the problem in a sensible way! After all, I am using a International board.... It makes total sense!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (prior to version 9.3.0, Karabiner was called KeyRemap4MacBook). It allows you to remap specific keys or change then entire keyboard layout, as [described here](http://lifehacker.com/5882684/the-best-keyboard-remapper-for-mac-os-x).

It is a powerful keyboard remapper that can change not only the functionality of keys and key combinations, but just about everything related to how a key repeats when you hold it down. Keyboard remappings are highly customizable (although it's not a so simple process). You can change practically anything: you can search through all the options and quickly find what you're looking for, or just browse by category.  It's very powerful and usage is pretty straightforward.

The drawback is that keyboard remapping functions are predefined and you can just check them off. If you want to add custom remapping functions, you have to edit an XML file. When you're using a GUI application this is not exactly the ideal experience. That said, this is the only significant drawback.

Comment: Thanks for this one...  I'm starting to do my taxes for 2017 and it was really bugging the crap out of me in excel!

Answer (score 1):

For the reverse that Panosru is looking for I believe that the correct syntax within ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict should be:

```
{
   "#." = ("insertText:". ",");
}
```

As the comma after "insertText" is a separator between the command and the wanted character.