# How to restore the default values on a keyboard in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, keyboard, keybindings

I used the `hidutil` function to remap several keys on my keyboard:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":
    [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000003e,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000004c},
     {"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000004c,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000003e} ,   
     {"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000003f,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000002a},
     {"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000002a,
      "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000003f}]
}'
```

My problem is that I made some mistakes in it, and I don't find the way to restore it.

Comment: reboot the machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reset the key mapping(s) back to default, simply make the "destination" the same as the "source"

For example,

```
hidutil property --set'{"UserKeyMapping": [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000003e,
  "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000003e}]'
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 13):

Passing empty string didn't work for me, i.e. it didn't deactivate existing remappings. However, passing an empty array did the trick.

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[]}'
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `[]` looks better than `""` indeed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the help doc of the command, the content following `--set` must be valid JSON. But setting the property to `null` takes no effect. Instead, I found either empty string actually works here:

`hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":""}'`