# Resetting right-alt (option) key on MacBook Pro 2017 Monterey 12.3

Tags: macos, keyboard, mission-control

**Problem**

My right alt (option) key is bound to the [Desktop feature of Mission Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Control_(macOS)) (the feature where all windows are pushed away to show a clean desktop). This feature is normally bound to either `Cmd-F3` or `F11` depending on the age of your keyboard/computer. By default the right option key should not do anything by itself I believe. I am pretty sure I bound this feature to the right option key a number of years ago in system preferences, since then the option to bind that feature has been removed (?). I would like to unbind this keyboard shortcut.

**What I tried**

I scoured system preferences both under the 'Keyboard' as well as the 'Accessibility' menu, without finding a way to (un-)bind the right option key.

I discovered the `hidutil` command for rebinding any key in macOS, but I did not use that at the time, making me apprehensive to use it. Using [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351531/how-to-restore-the-default-values-on-a-keyboard-in-terminal) page, I tried to reset the right option key, to no avail.

OS: Monterey 12.3
Device: MacBook Pro 2017

**Question**

How do I unbind that shortcut (right-alt (option)to the Desktop feature)?

Comment: macOS itself would not have let you map just right Alt to a function [it doesn't even usually differentiate between left & right alt, though it does know the difference internally.] I suspect you might have used Karabiner or similar to do this initially.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have installed Karabiner (now for the first time), it does not recognize that right alt was set to the Desktop feature. I can bind right alt to something else (right control for example) and then the Desktop shortcut is unbound. But setting the right alt button to right alt again, back from right control, results in the Desktop shortcut being enabled once again. It seems that the Desktop feature is bound to right-alt and that Karabiner works on a higher level, no?

Edit: The left alt is not bound to the Desktop feature, so the binding to right alt must be something internal then?

Comment: I guess. It's not something you can do from the regular UI, so I can't think how you did it, sorry. Maybe rather than unbinding with hidutil, you could change the binding back to default? Not something I've any experience with, I'm afraid.